# Using grep in linux to pipe all urls contained in an xml file to a seperate file

Tags: linux, grep, pipe

I have an xml file which looks like the following. How can I use grep to search through this file and pipe all the urls into a file seperated by a new line.

```
<menus>
    <defaultMenu>
        <group>
            <menuItem name="Example one" url="http://www.google.com">
                <menuItem name="Example Two" url="http://www.yahoo.com" />
                <menuItem name="Example Three" url="http://www.bing.com" />
            </menuItem>
        </group>
    </defaultMenu>
</menus>
```

For example I want the output file to contain:

```
http://www.google.com
http://www.yahoo.com
http://www.bing.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you like to try `gnu awk` (due to RS)

```
awk -v RS="url" -F\" 'NR>1{print $2}' file >newfile
http://www.google.com
http://www.yahoo.com
http://www.bing.com
```

---

A simple `awk`

```
awk -F\" '/url/{print $4}' file
http://www.google.com
http://www.yahoo.com
http://www.bing.com
```

This works only if format is same all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Through GNU sed,

```
$ sed -rn 's/^.*url="([^"]*)".*$/\1/p' file
http://www.google.com
http://www.yahoo.com
http://www.bing.com
```

And the one through GNU `grep` with `-P`(*perl-regex*) option,

```
$ grep -oP '(?<=url=\")[^"]*' file
http://www.google.com
http://www.yahoo.com
http://www.bing.com
```

Comment: You should write that you need `gnu grep` with the `-P`. Perl regular expression

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your file sample.html run the below command to get the url in `sample1.html` file

```
cat sample.html | grep -o url=\".*\" | cut -d "=" -f2 > sample1.html
```

and if you want to remove quotes also then

```
cat sample.html | grep -o url=\".*\" | cut -d "=" -f2 | sed "s/\"//g" > sample1.html
```

Comment: You should not use  `cat` with programs that can read it itself like `grep`.  `grep -o url=\".*\" sample.html | cut ...`

Comment: Click the `{}` in the help line to mark it as code.

Comment: Yup agree with you, instead of cat grep only will work here and that too fast thanks :)